# Drawing single graph in multivariable survival analysis using autoplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here, I have a dataset for survival analysis for breast cancer gene expression data. I have run through multi variable survival analysis of genes using `aareg()` function from `survival` package. I have used `autoplot()` function to draw survival curve for each of the gene in one frame, but I want to draw survival curve for each gene in separate frame. Please help. Here is my code

```
combined<-data.frame(ID=c(1:10),
                 rectime=sample(c(0,1),10,replace = TRUE),
                 BRCA1=sample(c("altered","normal"),10,replace = TRUE),
                 BRCA2=sample(c("altered","normal"),10,replace = TRUE),
                 BRCA3=sample(c("altered","normal"),10,replace = TRUE),
                 BRCA4=sample(c("altered","normal"),10,replace = TRUE),
                 BRCA5=sample(c("altered","normal"),10,replace = TRUE),
                 BRCA6=sample(c("altered","normal"),10,replace = TRUE),
                 BRCA7=sample(c("altered","normal"),10,replace = TRUE),
                 BRCA8=sample(c("altered","normal"),10,replace = TRUE),
                 BRCA9=sample(c("altered","normal"),10,replace = TRUE),
                 BRCA10=sample(c("altered","normal"),10,replace = TRUE),
                 BRCA11=sample(c("altered","normal"),10,replace = TRUE),
                 BRCA12=sample(c("altered","normal"),10,replace = TRUE)
```

)

```
library(survival)
library(ggfortify)
# combined contains data for covariates(i.e genes)
kmsurvo <- Surv(combined$Rectime, combined$Censor.Status)
fit_com <- aareg(kmsurvo~., data=combined[, 4:ncol(combined)])`

autoplot(fit_com)
```

This produces the following:

[image]

Comment: We do not have your data, so we cannot run your code. Is threesome sample data that you could use so that we could run the code for testing?

Comment: You need a column called `Censor.Status` in the example data.

Comment: rectime is that Censor.Status